# LibPNG static linking with VS2012 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, libpng

I can't manage to link LibPNG statically to my VS2012(64bit) project.
I did the following:

1. Download libPNG source code for the [latest version(1614)](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).
2. Open the enclosed VisualStudio solution (projects/vstudio/vstudio.sln).
3. Select "Release Library" and set C/C++ -> Code Generation ->Runtime Library to "MDd" (same as in my project.

   4.Compile static lib.

Then in the target project in the linker I specify in  **Additional Library directories**  the location of the lib and in the **Input** the name of the lib.

I also configured Zlib to be static as is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956398/static-libpng-link-with-visual-studio-2010).

Yet,when compiling I am getting :

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_sig_cmp referenced in
>   function

For the very first function call to LibPNG API.

I have tried to tweak different properties of the lib but it doesn't work.Can it happen because the libPNG built as x86 lib and not x64?

Comment: Of course it may happen when linking x86 with 64, that cannot be done, since the final assembly would have to contain code with 32bit pointers and 64bit pointers which is obviously wrong. Do you know the architecture of the lib? Why not compile both projects in the same architecture?

Comment: I wasn't sure it is important for C lib.Also the Visual Studio Project which ships with libPNG doesn't contain 64bit config.

Comment: Well, it might be a bit complicated to create your own 64bit config for libPNG since there might be code depending on 32bit environment, but it is worth the shot. If you need help with it, post your questions so we can try to help you with it.

Comment: @SatA you were completely right.I needed to change to x64 compile mode.Now it links.Gonna see it works ok.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to sum up the comments, the solution here was to compile libPNG in 64bit mode.

You cannot compile 32bit assembly with 64bit assembly.